# Is there anyways to store the data from the forms into variables without saving it to the database?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save the data inside a form into variables without saving it to the database but I don't know how. I'm not even sure if it's possible.

Comment: When you say form, do you mean in memory data, or do you mean in a physical file?

Comment: Sessions? Which will depending on the backenend of your choice also go to the database in most production setups.

Comment: @eatmeimadanish - A form within an HTML file. I'm using Django forms to ask user input but I want to be able to manipulate their data before storing it inside the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in the `ModelForm` won't be saved unless you explicitly call `save` on it, so you're free to read the data in `cleaned_data` and do with it what you want. If you're using a regular form, it's only saved into the database if you create/update a model instance by copying the data from `cleaned_data` into an instance.

For example:

```
def some_view(request):
   form = MyForm(request.POST)
   if form.is_valid():
       foo = form.cleaned_data['foo']
       # Do what you want with `foo`. Save to session, print to console, etc.
```